# Understanding glClearColor values

Tags: c++, opengl, rgb

I am trying to create a single OpenGL window with some background color picked in RGB color picker but it looks like I am missing something important in this function. When I want to set color to standard, for example red color, it works.

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

But when I want to set some exotic color like `184, 213, 238, 1` then it shows only white.

```
glClearColor(184.0f, 213.0f, 238.0f, 1.0f);
```

What am I doing wrong? And what are the decimal values for and also the `f` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the Khronos documentation page for [`glClearColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearColor.xhtml), which clearly says:

> `void glClearColor(GLfloat red, GLfloat green, GLfloat blue, GLfloat alpha);`
>
> `glClearColor` specifies the red, green, blue, and alpha values used by glClear to clear the color buffers. Values specified by glClearColor are clamped to the range [0,1].

This means the parameters are floating point values in the range from 0.0 to 1.0.
Adapt your code like this:

```
glClearColor(184.0f/255.0f, 213.0f/255.0f, 238.0f/255.0f, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here, rValue, gValue and bValue always between `0.0 f` to `1.0 f`. So if you want to apply color between 0 to 225.and alpha is also between `0.0 f` to  `1.0 f`. (0 for full transparent).

```
rValue= 184.0 / 255.0

gValue= 213.0 / 255.0

bValue= 238.0 / 255.0

glClearColor(rvalue, gValue, bValue, alpha);
```